# Elementary number theory - solving $x^3=y^3+2y^2-1$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find the integral solutions to
$$x^3=y^3+2y^2-1.$$

Here is my progress so far:

If $y=0$, then $x=-1$, so $(x,y)=(-1,0)$ is one solution.

If $y\neq 0$, then $2y^2-1>0$, so $x^3>y^3$, and thus $x>y$.

I have also noticed that
$$y^3+2y^2-1=(y+1)(y^2+y-1)=(y+1)\left(\left(y+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2-\dfrac{5}{4}\right),$$
but I cannot see how to proceed. Can anyone give me a hint?

EDIT: I have also noticed that $y<x<y+1$ when $y<-2$ or $y>-1$.

Comment: If you want the solution over integers, then it's x = (-1)^(2/3) (y^3 + 2 y^2 - 1)^(1/3) and y element Z. If you want I can detail.

Comment: @ArthurGuiot Yes, but how can this be used to show that there are only two possible pairs of integers $(x,y)$? In other words, if $y$ is an integer, when is $(-1)^{2/3}(y^3+2y^2-1)^{1/3}$ an integer?

Comment: It will work for y = -1 for example

Comment: @ArthurGuiot The goal is to find every $y$ for which it works

Comment: woo I added negative $y,$ which does give some solutions to the original problem, as your title says $\mathbb Z$ rather than, say, $\mathbb N$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for example, when $y \geq 1,$ then
$$  y^3 < y^3 + 2 y^2 - 1 < (y+1)^3 $$
and so the $y^3 + 2 y^2 - 1$ cannot be an integer cube

If you wish to consider negative numbers, take $w \geq 3$ and $y = -w.$ In any case $- w^3 < -w^3 + 2 w^2 - 1.$ Next comes 
$$ (1-w)^3  = -w^3 + 3 w^2 - 3 w + 1 = (-w^3 + 2^2 - 1) + (w^2 - 3w + 2),$$
where $w \geq 3$ gives us $w^2 - 3w + 2 > 0.$ Together, we get
$$ -w^3 < -w^3 + 2 w^2 - 1 < (1-w)^3  $$ 
when $w \geq 3.$

You need check only $y = -2,-1,0.$ All three give cubes!